# Не применяются миграции в yii2

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, миграция

у меня не применяются миграции. Ввожу команду `php yii migrate` и тут выходит ошибка:

```
u0498223@u0498223.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/coinfactory.pw]# php yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.15.1)

Total 3 new migrations to be applied:
    m180601_153539_create_user_table
    m180604_124322_drop_user_table
    m180604_124811_create_user_table

Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m180601_153539_create_user_table
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class m180601_153539_create_user_table does not exist'

in /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(428): ReflectionClass->__construct('m180601_153539_...')
#1 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(364): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('m180601_153539_...')
#2 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('m180601_153539_...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('m180601_153539_...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(202): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#5 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(724): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->createMigration('m180601_153539_...')
#6 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(199): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateUp('m180601_153539_...')
#7 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
#8 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#10 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(148): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#11 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#12 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
#13 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
#14 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#15 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

m180601_153539_create_user_table.php

```
<?php
use yii\db\Migration;
/**
* Handles the creation of table `user`.
*/
class m180601_153539_create_user_table extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
    }
    $this->createTable('{{%user}}', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'username' => $this->string()->notNull()->unique(),
        'auth_key' => $this->string(32)->notNull(),
        'password_hash' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'password_reset_token' => $this->string()->unique(),
        'email' => $this->string()->notNull()->unique(),

        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
    ], $tableOptions);
}
public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('{{%user}}');
}
```

}

console.php

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'params' => $params,
    /*
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [ // Fixture generation command line.
            'class' => 'yii\faker\FixtureController',
        ],
    ],
    */
];
```

db.php

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u0498223_coinfactory',
    'username' => 'u0498223_coin',
    'password' => '60592swallow',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'pref_',

    'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    'enableQueryCache' => true,
];
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по ошибке проблема в файле миграции `m180601_153539_create_user_table` покажите файл в котором описывается эта миграция и файл конфигурации подключения к бд для консольного приложения. Подобный вопрос уже [был](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674847/yii2-migration-problems) на англ. SO.

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry Я обновила свой вопрос и прописала там файлы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас имя миграции `m180601_153539_create_user_table`, а класс `m170903_114309_create_user_table`. Переименуйте чтобы имя файла и класса миграции совпадало.

Поскольку имена разные миграция не может найти класса с нужным именем. Будьте внимательны при копировании миграций. Я никогда не копирую имена классов миграций, только код таблицы.

Comment: Да, я тоже только что заметила.. увы это моя не внимательность. Спасибо вам большое)

Comment: @GaLana  `невнимательность`

Comment: @Manitikyl Быстро печатаю..И уже на ошибки нет времени обращать внимания..))

Comment: @GaLana из-за того, что Вы быстро печатает и у Вас нет времени обращать внимание на ошибки, Вы и задали последние вопросов 5 на ruSO

Comment: @Peresada Да у меня что-то вообще вчера какой-то день неудачный был(